# In Terminator 2: Judgment Day, why didn't the T-1000 assume the form of Todd or Janelle (John's foster parents)?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Why didn't the T-1000 assume the form of Todd or Janelle (John's foster parents), or even just a stranger rather than remaining in the form of the police officer? The only reason John had a head start, and eventually escaped (with the help of the T-800), is because his friend warned him that a police officer was looking for him. John probably assumed that it was because they had just robbed an ATM and was trying to flee. I feel that the T-1000 would have had a higher chance of achieving its mission in almost any other form, and perhaps could have terminated John quickly at the Galleria rather than engaging in a foot chase, thereby giving the T-800 a chance to catch up and ultimately help John escape.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT_u9Rurrqg

Comment: This clip takes place after the chase at the mall and after the T-800 had already found John. The T-1000 had already been to his foster parent's house to see if they knew where he'd gone, which would have been the perfect opportunity to take on one of their forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a police officer gives the T-1000 a very distinct advantage in its *current* task, locating John Connor in a hurry so that it can terminate him. Not only does the form engender respect in those that it speaks to (far more so than would a stranger in casual clothes) but it also allows it to task other non-law-enforcement individuals to do its bidding.

> The two ten-year-old girls stood in front of the Subway sandwich shop and shyly studied the photo the policeman had offered them. He was leaning out the cruiser window with a broad smile that would have been warm had it not been so forced. One of the girls looked away from his strange expression, instinctively uneasy. The other, not noticing, said, “Yeah, he was here about fifteen minutes ago. I think he said he was going to the Galleria.”

and

> He glanced over at a security guard who was eyeing him curiously.
> Austin considered the possible alternatives and a second later walked
> up to the man and showed him the photo, asking him to look out for the
> boy.
>
> <sub><sup>[T2: Judgement Day - Official Novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

Given its extremely limited knowledge of John, it could reasonably have expected him *not to bolt* when approached by a police officer.

---

Later on, and having blown its cover and with no major leads to go on to find John, it assumes Janelle's form in the hopes that John will decide to come back home.

Comment: For the record, there's every possibility that John would have tried to evade Todd or Janelle at the mall

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I see your point that appearing as a police officer would give the T-1000 an advantage in finding John so that he could terminate him, but it had already been informed that John was most likely at the Galleria, and at that point it could have taken the form of somebody familiar to John. And yes, based on the limited information the T-1000 had on John, the terminator had no reason to believe that John would run from a police officer. But using the same logic, it would have been a valid assumption that John would most likely not run if approached by a family member.

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - The goal is to find him as expeditiously as possibly, then run at him with a gun. People are more likely to tell a policeman where to find someone (from a picture) than just a random member of the public wandering around asking which would, additionally, attract unwanted attention from the police and security staff

Comment: People would be willing to help find him, especially if the T-1000 took Janelle's form. While many people are wary of police officers and try to avoid them if possible, a mother using a photo to search for her son in a busy mall would not be seen as abnormal and may even prompt good Samaritans, police and security staff to help the T-1000 locate John.

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - Unless she bumped into someone that knew Janelle, which would raise suspicions since she wouldn't know anything about her/them.

Comment: That's a big " ". The odds of that happening are pretty slim, but  the T-1000 ran into someone who knew Janelle, that person would likely just join in the effort to find him rather than wasting time by engaging in any small talk with her that could raise any suspicions.

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - Next time we see the security guard, he's still engaged in a hunt for the boy. Additionally, he sees a gunfight and instinctively sides with what he thinks is the policeman; "*Officer Austin appeared at the railing, swatting aside a store mannequin that had gotten entangled around his leg, and glanced down. The security guard lowered the gun, uncertain, as he saw the cop abruptly turn and walk out of sight.*" - Would he have done the same if the T-1000 was running around **looking like Janelle and toting a Beretta?**

Comment: No, the security guard would not have reacted the same, but that is irrelevant. There was no gunfight until after John had been alerted about the "police officer" by his friend and bolted. Perhaps the entire gunfight could have been avoided had the T-1000 been in Janelle's form the entire time.

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - Or the T-1000 could have been shot as soon as it took out its gun in a busy mall

Comment: Unless it calculated an almost 100% chance of terminating John with the first shot, it likely would have used one of its limbs to fashion a blade rather than using the pistol.

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - Pointy sticks are not as deadly as chips of metal moving at hundreds of miles per hour

Comment: Yes, but when stealth is required, sometimes guns aren't an option. The "pointy sticks" can be formed in an instant and are quite deadly as well. The T-1000 could have done exactly what it did to Todd to John at the arcade. youtube.com/watch?v=MT_u9Rurrqg

Comment: @frigid_nihilism - We've wandered into a second question; ***"Why did the T-1000 use a gun when it can kill at a reasonable range using its body"***